# Unable to connect relationship between two tables (Error cannot insert value )

Tags: sql, sql-server, datatable

I'm currently making a relationship between Product and Order(DonHang) and for some reason I got this error message said that:

> cannot insert a null value into column Quantity.

After I searched and applied several configurations, it remains the same error.

What I did:

- Input data onto the Product Table
- Identity Specification switch to YES
- Generate Table through Query
- Two of those tables have Primary Key being set

I don't know what is the problem that leads to this issue.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Your `Quantity` column doesn't allow null values, but also doesn't have a default value. The operation you are trying to perform is obviously trying to insert a null value. Given you don't allow nulls I imagine you probably want to set a default on `Quantity` of maybe zero?

Comment: @Dale K I want to set Quantity to be like at least put some data onto it and this. In which why I don't allow nulls in the column due to the fact that would not want any information to be blank. I might be wrong with this statement but a clarification would be nice.

Comment: My guess is that SSMS is dropping the table and recreating it under the hood, or something like that. You could try scripting the relationship instead as that won't do anything unexpected.

Comment: @DaleK Well, in that case, it is possible to form the relationship on MS access? Or you need to do the relationship directly from MS SQL

Comment: You need some way of running a SQL against the database... I don't know if that is possible from Access.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error message is clear !
**cannot insert a null value into column Quantity.**
this error is about inserting null into field **Quantity** that is **NOT NULL**

try these :

```
--alter column Quantity  to accept nulls
1- ALTER TABLE PRODUCTION ALTER COLUMN Quantity INT NULL
```

OR

```
--alter column Quantity  to set default value 0 if it is null
2- ALTER TABLE PRODUCTION  add constraint dt_Quantity default 0 for Quantity
```

Comment: Hey I have applied code and it doesn't work. The error still remains despite query being applied successfull

Comment: @PhạmQuốcMinhĐăng thats not possible - maybe you applied it to a different table or database. But if you run either of these scripts they will prevent the error you are showing.

Comment: @DaleK Hey, thanks for revealing my mistake. I really appreciated it. I got it working